# Skip wrapping element

Tags: json, jq

I have a couple of files, each having a differently named wrapper element. For example: `{"a":{"x":0}}` and  `{"b":{"y":1, "z":2}}`.

Who can I select the content of the most outer wrapping element without selecting it by name?

Comment: What about the "content". Is it always the same structure? What technology do you use to process the files?

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. No, the content differs. I updated the question.

Comment: What programming language do you use to open the file?

Comment: Just shell using jq in the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jq` like this:

```
jq -r 'to_entries[0].value' file.json
```

---

Explanation:

The `to_entries` function will transform the json like this:

```
jq 'to_entries[0]' <<< '{"b":{"y":1, "z":2}}'
{
  "key": "b",
  "value": {
    "y": 1,
    "z": 2
  }
}
```

Adding `.value` gives you the value only.

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 1):

Even easier:

```
jq '.[]'
```

Output (with the -c option):

```
{"x":0}
{"y":1,"z":2}
```